# python, NoneType object has no attribute '__getitem__', MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql

```
def getRowFromPolynomes(self, paramId):
    qry = 'SELECT * FROM polynomes WHERE par_id = %d' % paramId
    self.edb.curs.execute(qry)
    row = self.edb.curs.fetchone()
    return row

def fixPolynomes(self):
    rowCount = self.edb.curs.execute('SELECT par_id FROM params')
    for x in xrange(0, rowCount):

        # THE PROGRAM FAILS AT THIS LINE, HOWEVER paramId is correctly received.
        # IT IS CORRECTLY PRINTED, NAMELY THE 28731 AT THE BEGINNING OF MY OUTPUT
        paramId =  self.edb.curs.fetchone()[0]
        print paramId

        result = self.getRowFromPolynomes(paramId)
        if result is None:
            self.addRowToPolynomes(1, paramId)
```

The number 2873 is the expected output from `self.edb.curs.fetchone()[0]`, it is correctly printed, still the program fails at line 45 which is the line `paramId = self.deb.curs.fetchone()[0]`

I don't get it, what am I missing here?

My output:

```
>>> 28371
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "db.py", line 60, in <module>
    db.fixPolynomes()
  File "db.py", line 45, in fixPolynomes
    paramId =  self.edb.curs.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: When is the first time you called fetchone()?

Comment: Why not just loop *directly* over the cursor? `for row in self.edb.curs:` will yield rows.

Comment: @Rod I call the function fixPolynomes, This retrieves the entire column `par_id` from the table `params` and then the fetchone method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `self.edb.curs` in both methods, so during the first iteration cursor is fetching one row for query:

```
SELECT par_id FROM params
```

but then inside this loop you call:

```
result = self.getRowFromPolynomes(paramId)
```

and this method uses the same cursor to execute query:

```
SELECT * FROM polynomes WHERE par_id = %d
```

so results of the first query are wiped out but the value of `rowCount` in:

```
for x in xrange(0, rowCount):
```

remains the same.

The latter query returned only one row sow next call to `fetchone()`:

```
paramId = self.edb.curs.fetchone()[0]
```

indeed returns `None` and `NoneType` indeed doesn't have the method `__getitem__` so access by index fails.

**Solution:**

```
def fixPolynomes(self):
    self.edb.curs.execute(
        'SELECT params.par_id, polynomes.* FROM params LEFT OUTER JOIN polynomes ON params.par_id = polynomes.par_id'
    )
    for result in self.edb.curs:
        if result[1] is None:
            self.addRowToPolynomes(1, paramId)
```

You can adjust this but method `getRowFromPolynomes(self, paramId)` is definitely not needed since you can join two tables in one query.
*Thanks @Mertijn for your comment. I knew about it but I just wanted to make only absolutely necessary changes to OP's code. Anyway, I've just corrected this because you're right.*

Comment: The loop over `xrange(0, rowCount)` is an anti-pattern here. Just call `.execute()` (ignore the return value), then iterate *directly* over the cursor, which yields rows.